# Configuring TCP keep_alive with boost::asio

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio

Both Linux and Windows support TCP `keep-alive` packets. They can be activated and configured with (system-dependent) `setsockopt` calls, see e.g. [this article](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/programming.html) for the Linux case. When using `boost::asio` there appears to be support for keep-alive messages, see [the current documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/keep_alive.html). However that page only covers activating it. In several new responses to an [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291871/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-blocking-sockets-in-boost-asio) it was pointed out that Boost has recently added the means to configure timeouts on operations (which obviates the need for `setsockopt` and `#ifdef` code-branches for different systems). However, a [recent response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568672/boost-asio-how-can-a-server-know-if-a-client-is-still-connected) still suggests calls on the native sockets.

My question is: How can I configure the time interval and timeouts of keep-alive packets using `boost::asio`?

Comment: @KillianDS The post you quote deals with the `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO` options. The current questions specifically deals with other constants. If you read the referenced article you'll find that the raw options on Linux systems are `TCP_KEEPIDLE` and `TCP_KEEPINTVL`. Furthermore, the accepted answer suggests to use raw sockets which I explicitly tried to avoid.

Comment: no it doesn't, it takes a native handle, that is not the same as a raw socket. And while it might talk about different options than you want, the procedure is *exactly* the same (you even accepted a very similar answer here, that uses the same options).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure both the send timeout and receive timeout using the setsockopt options.  Here is some platform-dependent code to do this on both windows and linux / unix, the example sets both send and receive timeouts to the same ten second value:

```
// start IO service    
io_context = new boost::asio::io_context;        

// define a tcp socket object    
tcpsocket = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(*io_context); 

// the timeout value
unsigned int timeout_milli = 10000;

// platform-specific switch
#if defined _WIN32 || defined WIN32 || defined OS_WIN64 || defined _WIN64 || defined WIN64 || defined WINNT
  // use windows-specific time
  int32_t timeout = timeout_milli;
  setsockopt(tcpsocket->native_handle(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
  setsockopt(tcpsocket->native_handle(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (const char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
#else
  // assume everything else is posix
  struct timeval tv;
  tv.tv_sec  = timeout_milli / 1000;
  tv.tv_usec = (timeout_milli % 1000) * 1000;
  setsockopt(tcpsocket->native_handle(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv));
  setsockopt(tcpsocket->native_handle(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv));
#endif
```

Comment: So the answer is that `boost::asio` only allows activating it, but does not offer any way to configure it. I'll go with your solution, then. After all, it is not actually a problem to use native sockets.

Comment: Indeed - I suppose the rationale is that not every implementation would allow the same configuration options, so asio chooses to leave potentially platform-specific configuration to the user.

Comment: @Riot have you seen the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292997/can-you-set-so-rcvtimeo-and-so-sndtimeo-socket-options-in-boost-asio? I was going to use a solution like yours, but apparently it doesn't work well with asio...

Comment: @kenba that top answer uses the same setsockopt solution here.  I can confirm it works just fine with asio, i've been using this for a long time.  The second answer there is nonsense, there's no need to inject anything into the asio namespace, just access the platform-dependent socket handles directly.  That's all asio itself does behind the nice friendly wrapper, anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Riot it's the second one that I was worried about! I'm glad to hear that your solution's fine, I'll use it myself now.

Comment: Honestly this doesn't answer the OP's question. Keepalive values are set with SOL_TCP, {TCP_KEEPIDLE, TCP_KEEPINTVL, TCP_KEEPCNT} on posix and enabled with SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE

Comment: Actually, the OP's comment is "can you set ... socket options **in boost asio**?  My answer is asio-specific; your comment just refers to posix.  Boost asio also applies to non-posix systems.

Comment: This works but seems like it is not very reliable? If I switch off the wifi for example then my `boost::asio::async_read` never returns.

Comment: For keep-alive packets it seems that the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669005/tcp-keepalive-protocol-not-available describes the options to change (TCP_KEEPCNT, TCP_KEEPIDLE, and TCP_KEEPINTVL for level IPPROTO_TCP instead of SOL_SOCKET).