# tcp keepalive - Protocol not available?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to set tcp keepalive but in doing so I'm seeing the error

"Protocol not available"

```
int rc = setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &keepalive_idle, sizeof(keepalive_idle));
if (rc < 0)
    printf("error setting keepalive_idle: %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

I'm able to turn on keepalive, set keepalive interval and count but keepalive idle which is keepalive time is throwing that error and I never see any keepalive packets being transmitted/received either with wireshark and the filter `tcp.analysis.keep_alive` or with tcpdump

```
sudo tcpdump -vv "tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-ack and less 1"
```

Is there a kernel module that needs to be loaded or something? Or are you no longer able to override the global KEEPIDLE time.

By the way the output of

```
matt@devpc:~/ sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
```

Comment: tcp_keepalive_time is the time in seconds before the first keepalive packet is sent. According to your example, it is set to 2 hours. Did you really wait that long? Reduce it and try again.

Comment: @KBart - exactly. That's the default.  I'm wanting to change it from the default but it's giving me "Protocol not available."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an application that I coded, the following works:

```
setsockopt(*sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE,(char *)&enable_keepalive, sizeof(enable_keepalive));
setsockopt(*sfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, (char *)&num_keepalive_strobes, sizeof(num_keepalive_strobes));
setsockopt(*sfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, (char *)&keepalive_idle_time_secs, sizeof(keepalive_idle_time_secs));
setsockopt(*sfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, (char *)&keepalive_strobe_interval_secs, sizeof(keepalive_strobe_interval_secs));
```

Try changing `SOL_SOCKET` to `IPPROTO_TCP` for `TCPKEEPIDLE`.

Comment: Doh! thanks Prabhu.  I had SOL_SOCKET as the second parameter for all the options.  It's working now!

Answer (score 2):

There a very handy lib that can help you, it's called `libkeepalive` : http://libkeepalive.sourceforge.net/

It can be used with `LD_PRELOAD` in order to enable and control keep-alive on all TCP sockets. You can also override keep-alive settings with environment variables.

I tried to run a tcp server with it:

```
KEEPIDLE=5 KEEPINTVL=5 KEEPCNT=100 LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libkeepalive.so nc -l -p 4242
```

Then I connected a client:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 4242
```

And I visualized the traffic with Wireshark: the keep-alive packets began exactly after 5 seconds of inactivity (my system wide setting is 75). Therefore it means that it's possible to override the system settings.

Here is how `libkeepalive` sets `TCP_KEEPIDLE`:

```
  if((env = getenv("KEEPIDLE")) && ((optval = atoi(env)) >= 0)) {
    setsockopt(s, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &optval, sizeof(optval));
  }
```

Looks like they use `SOL_TCP` instead of `SOL_SOCKET`.

Comment: Can't use it.  I'm not writing GPL code so can't link to it either.  I just want to have what should work, work.

Comment: Ok, but I told you that your code probably doesn't work because you use SOL_SOCKET and libkeepalive uses SOL_TCP.

Comment: Appreciate that, but it only required changing SOL_SOCKET to IPPROTO_TCP. Fixed.